# single or plural in the name "6 minute English"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

There is a famous learning programes series "BBC 6 minute English".

[6-minute-english](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/oromo/features/6-minute-english)

6 is large than 1 ,it means more or plural,we use its plural format "minutes" in the below sentence:

> He stood in the shower for six minutes.

Why do it use "6 minute English" , instead of "6 minutes English" ?

Comment: When a number + noun is used in an adjective, the noun is never pluralized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Units are used in their singular form when they are used before a noun to describe it:

> A three-metre snake  (But "The snake was three metres long")

> A five-pound bag of sugar

> A four-hour journey

This is consistent with other uses of attributive nouns, that are normally singular:

> A apartment building  (even though it has many apartments)

So "Six-minute English" is consistent with this, and is not incorrect.